# Pivot Table Issue: Code Run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue that is making me go crazy.

Attached is the code

```
Sub Pivot()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ptField As PivotField
Dim ptRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

' Set the worksheet where you want to create the pivot table
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
ws.Cells.Clear
' Define the data range for the pivot table
Dim sheet_from As Worksheet
Set sheet_from = ActiveSheet
last_row = sheet_from.Range("A65336").End(xlUp).Row
Set ptRange = sheet_from.Range("A2:BJ" & last_row)

' Create a pivot table on a new sheet or existing sheet
Set pt = ws.Parent.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                                     TableName:="PivotTable4")

' Add fields to the pivot table
With pt
    ' Add fields to rows
    
    Set ptField = .PivotFields("Narrative1")
    ptField.Orientation = xlRowField
    
    ' Add fields to values
    Set ptField = .PivotFields("Column1") ' Change "Amount" to your field name
    ptField.Orientation = xlDataField
    ptField.Function = xlSum ' You can change the function as needed (e.g., xlCount, xlAverage, etc.)
    
    
     With .DataPivotField
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End With
sheet_from.Activate
```

End Sub

The issue is on

```
Set pt = ws.Parent.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                                 TableName:="PivotTable4")
```

What is confusing is, I made this from record macro and edit it from another sheet and it works fine. When I change the details to the specs on this sheet, initially, it created successfully. But the weird thing is, the column 1 is created twice, despite I only put the requirement once. It would show as `Column1_2`.

When I try to rerun the code after that, I receive error code 1004. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: ws.Parent is the workbook which hasn't `PivotTableWizard`. Worksheet or PivotTable has.

Comment: The macro uses `Set sheet_from = ActiveSheet` so be careful which sheet is active when you run the macro. If you run the macro while `Sheet2` is active, it will clear everything on `Sheet2`, and throw the 1004 error on the line you indicated.

Comment: Hi, Im sorry, I understand what you mean @kevin but I do not know how to make the solution. Say I want to pull the data from Sheet: Abcefg, how would I be able to replace the activesheet and pull the data to sheet 2. Thank you

Comment: You would activate sheet Abcefg, and run the macro. It seems like you also need to select a cell within the data on sheet Abcefg. You shouldn't get the error at `Set pt`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. THe part where I'm confused is on this one: Set pt = ws.Parent.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                                     TableName:="PivotTable4") where the code is having issue on recognizing pivottable4, despite I already name it. How do I activate sheet abcefg? Again, sorry if this question seems dumb, im still new at this

Comment: Click on sheet abcefg